# How to display container contains tablelayout of 7 columns in center of the screen for all resolution screens in code name one

Tags: width, codenameone, resolution

Currently we are displaying the container that contains the table layout with 7 columns in center of the screen in the 1280x800 pixels resolution.

But we need the same container displaying in the 1920x1200 pixels resolution in center of the screen.

Actually the container is displayed but the row data is missing. Is anything wrong in my code? Please help me how to resolve this one.

```
FlowLayout centerLayout = new FlowLayout();
centerLayout.setAlign(Component.CENTER);
centerLayout.setValign(Component.TOP);

Container centerContainer = new Container(centerLayout);
topTabelcontainer = new Container(new TableLayout(7, 1));

commonComponentsForm = new CommonComponentsForm();
eventPostSchedulesForm = commonComponentsForm.setEventPostSchedulesFormHeader(eventPostSchedulesForm, res, workerBreaksPreferences);
topTabelcontainer = commonComponentsForm.getEventInfoHeader(eventPostSchedulesForm, res, topTabelcontainer, "showroster");

filterLayoutContainer = this.getFilterBody();
postScheduleTableContainer = this.getEventPostScheduleTable();

TableLayout.Constraint postScheduleTableConstraint = new TableLayout.Constraint();
postScheduleTableConstraint.setHorizontalAlign(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_SCALE);
postScheduleTableConstraint.setVerticalAlign(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_SCALE);

topTabelcontainer.add(filterLayoutContainer);
headerContainer);
topTabelcontainer.add(postScheduleTableConstraint, postScheduleTableContainer);
centerContainer.add(topTabelcontainer);

centerContainer.setScrollableY(Boolean.TRUE);
centerContainer.setTactileTouch(Boolean.TRUE);

centerContainer.addPointerDraggedListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        float val = Display.getInstance().getDragSpeed(false);
        boolean upperFlag = false;
        if (Display.getInstance().isPortrait()) {
            if (portRaitUpperBound < toralRecourdsCount)
                upperFlag = true;
        } else if (landScapeUpperBound < toralRecourdsCount)
            upperFlag = true;

        boolean lowerFlag = false;
        if (Display.getInstance().isPortrait()) {
            if ((portRaitLowerBound > 0 && portRaitLowerBound <= toralRecourdsCount))
                lowerFlag = true;
        } else if (landScapeLowerBound > 0 && landScapeLowerBound < toralRecourdsCount)
            lowerFlag = true;

        if (val >= 0.5 && scrollFlag) {
            dragFlag = true;
            if (upperFlag) {
                scrollFlag = false;
                setPageUpperAndLowerBound(Constants.NEXTFLAG);
                postScheduleTableContainer.removeAll();
                setEventPostScheduleTable(postScheduleTableContainer);
                eventPostSchedulesForm.revalidate();
            }
        } else if (val <= -0.5 && scrollFlag) {
            dragFlag = true;
            if (lowerFlag) {
                scrollFlag = false;
                setPageUpperAndLowerBound(Constants.PREVIOUSFLAG);
                postScheduleTableContainer.removeAll();
                setEventPostScheduleTable(postScheduleTableContainer);
                eventPostSchedulesForm.revalidate();
            }
        }
    }
});

eventPostSchedulesForm.setUIID("workersListForm");
eventPostSchedulesForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, centerContainer);
commonComponentsForm.getFooterTag(eventPostSchedulesForm);
eventPostSchedulesForm.show();
}

public Container getEventPostSchedulesTableHeader(Container postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer) {

    Label position = new Label(Constants.POSITION, searchingButtonImage);
    Label name = new Label(Constants.NAME, searchingButtonImage);
    Label callInOutLabel = new Label(Constants.CALLINOUT);
    position.setTextPosition(LEFT);
    name.setTextPosition(LEFT);

    TextArea actualCallIn1 = null;
    Label actualCallIn = null;

    TextArea actualCallOut1 = null;
    Label actualCallOut = null;

    TextArea agencyWorker1 = null;
    Label agencyWorker = null;
    if (Display.getInstance().isPortrait()) {
        actualCallIn1 = new TextArea(Constants.ACTUALCALLIN);
        actualCallIn1.setEditable(false);
        actualCallIn1.setFocusable(false);
        actualCallIn1.setColumns(3);
        actualCallIn1.setVerticalAlignment(Component.CENTER);

        actualCallOut1 = new TextArea(Constants.ACTUALCALLOUT);
        actualCallOut1.setEditable(false);
        actualCallOut1.setFocusable(false);
        actualCallOut1.setColumns(3);
        actualCallOut1.setVerticalAlignment(Component.CENTER);

        agencyWorker1 = new TextArea(Constants.AGENCYWORKER);
        agencyWorker1.setEditable(false);
        agencyWorker1.setFocusable(false);
        agencyWorker1.setColumns(3);
        agencyWorker1.setVerticalAlignment(Component.CENTER);
    } else {
        agencyWorker = new Label(Constants.AGENCYWORKER);
        actualCallIn = new Label(Constants.ACTUALCALLIN);
        actualCallOut = new Label(Constants.ACTUALCALLOUT);

    }
    Label workerBreak = new Label("  ");


    position.setUIID("workerTableHeader");
    name.setUIID("workerTableHeader");
    callInOutLabel.setUIID("workerTableHeader");

    if (Display.getInstance().isPortrait()) {
        agencyWorker1.setUIID("workerTableHeader");
        actualCallIn1.setUIID("workerTableHeader");
        actualCallOut1.setUIID("workerTableHeader");
    } else {
        agencyWorker.setUIID("workerTableHeader");
        actualCallIn.setUIID("workerTableHeader");
        actualCallOut.setUIID("workerTableHeader");
    }
    workerBreak.setUIID("workerTableHeader");


    if (Display.getInstance().isPortrait()) {
        postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(16, 8), position);
        postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(15, 8), name);
        postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(24, 8), callInOutLabel);
        postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(13, 8), actualCallIn1);
        postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(13, 8), actualCallOut1);
        postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.add(getTableConstraint(13, 8), agencyWorker1);
        if (workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks() != null && !"".equals(workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks()) && "1".equals(workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks()))
            postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(6, 8), workerBreak);
    } else {
        postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(13, 10), position);
        postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(18, 10), name);
        postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(20, 10), callInOutLabel);
        postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(13, 10), actualCallIn);
        postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(13, 10), actualCallOut);
        postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(16, 10), agencyWorker);
        if (workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks() != null && !"".equals(workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks()) && "1".equals(workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks()))
            postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(7, 10), workerBreak);
    }

    return postSchedulesTableHeaderContainer;
}

public Container getEventPostScheduleTable() {
    List < WorkerBean > eventPostSchedulesList = null;
    roasterDao = RoasterDao.getInstance();
    if (Display.getInstance().isPortrait()) {
        eventPostSchedulesList = roasterDao.getEventPostSchedulesDetails(positionFilterValue, nameFilterValue, portRaitLowerBound, portRaitPageSize);
    } else {
        eventPostSchedulesList = roasterDao.getEventPostSchedulesDetails(positionFilterValue, nameFilterValue, landScapeLowerBound, landScapePageSize);
    }
    int tableRowCount = Constants.INITIALTABLEROWS;
    boolean pagingFlag = false;
    int eventPostScheduleCount = roasterDao.getEventPostSchedulesCount(positionFilterValue, nameFilterValue);
    this.toralRecourdsCount = eventPostScheduleCount;

    FlowLayout centerLayout = new FlowLayout();
    centerLayout.setAlign(Component.CENTER);
    postScheduleTableContainer = new Container(centerLayout);
    postScheduleTableContainer.setUIID("tableBodyContainer");

    if (eventPostSchedulesList.size() > landScapePageSize) {
        tableRowCount = landScapePageSize + 1;
    } else {
        tableRowCount = eventPostSchedulesList.size() + 1;
    }

    Container borderTopPagingContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout());

    if (eventPostScheduleCount > landScapePageSize) {
        pagingFlag = true;
        if (Display.getInstance().isPortrait()) {
            borderTopPagingContainer = this.setHeaderPaging(eventPostScheduleCount, portRaitLowerBound, portRaitUpperBound, res);
        } else {
            borderTopPagingContainer = this.setHeaderPaging(eventPostScheduleCount, landScapeLowerBound, landScapeUpperBound, res);
        }
    }
    if (pagingFlag) {
        tableRowCount = tableRowCount + 1;
    }

    int columnCount = 6;
    if (workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks() != null && !"".equals(workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks()) && "1".equals(workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks()))
        columnCount++;
    Container postSchedulesListContainer = new Container(new TableLayout(tableRowCount, columnCount));

    if (pagingFlag) {
        TableLayout.Constraint postSchedulesListConstraint1 = new TableLayout.Constraint();
        postSchedulesListConstraint1.setHorizontalSpan(columnCount);
        postSchedulesListContainer.add(postSchedulesListConstraint1, borderTopPagingContainer);
    }

    postSchedulesListContainer = this.getEventPostSchedulesTableHeader(postSchedulesListContainer);

    String callInDBValue = "";
    String callOutDBValue = "";
    String actCallInDBValue = "";
    String actCallOutDBValue = "";
    Label position = null;
    Label name = null;
    Label callInOutLabel = null;
    Label actualCallIn = null;
    Label actualCallOut = null;
    TextField agencyWorker = null;
    Label workerBreak = null;

    for (WorkerBean eventPostSchedules: eventPostSchedulesList) {

        callInDBValue = "";
        if (eventPostSchedules != null) {
            if (eventPostSchedules.getCallIn().length() > 10)
                callInDBValue = eventPostSchedules.getCallIn().substring(10).trim();
            else {
                if (Constants.PLATFORMNAME.equals(Display.getInstance().getPlatformName()))
                    callInDBValue = "              ";
                else
                    callInDBValue = "              ";
            }
        }

        callOutDBValue = "";
        if (eventPostSchedules != null) {
            if (eventPostSchedules.getCallOut().length() > 10)
                callOutDBValue = eventPostSchedules.getCallOut().substring(10).trim();
            else {
                if (Constants.PLATFORMNAME.equals(Display.getInstance().getPlatformName()))
                    callOutDBValue = "              ";
                else
                    callOutDBValue = "              ";
            }
        }

        actCallInDBValue = "";
        if (eventPostSchedules != null) {
            if (eventPostSchedules.getActCallIn().length() > 10)
                actCallInDBValue = eventPostSchedules.getActCallIn().substring(10).trim();
            else
                actCallInDBValue = eventPostSchedules.getActCallIn().trim();
        }

        actCallOutDBValue = "";
        if (null != eventPostSchedules) {
            if (eventPostSchedules.getActCallOut().length() > 10)
                actCallOutDBValue = eventPostSchedules.getActCallOut().substring(10).trim();
            else
                actCallOutDBValue = eventPostSchedules.getActCallOut().trim();
        }
        callInDBValue = ((callInDBValue.trim().length() < 8) ? "  ".concat(callInDBValue) : callInDBValue) + ((callOutDBValue.trim().equals("")) ? callOutDBValue : " - " + callOutDBValue);
        position = new Label(eventPostSchedules.getPersonnelType());
        name = new Label(eventPostSchedules.getName());
        callInOutLabel = new Label(callInDBValue);
        actualCallIn = new Label(actCallInDBValue);
        actualCallIn.setFocusable(Boolean.TRUE);
        actualCallIn.addPointerPressedListener(createActualCallChangeListener(actualCallIn, eventPostSchedules.getSerialId(), Constants.ACTUALCALLINFLAG, eventPostSchedules.getName(), eventPostSchedules.getActCallIn(), eventPostSchedules.getActCallOut(), eventPostSchedules.getActCallIn()));

        actualCallOut = new Label(actCallOutDBValue);
        actualCallOut.setFocusable(Boolean.TRUE);
        actualCallOut.addPointerPressedListener(createActualCallChangeListener(actualCallOut, eventPostSchedules.getSerialId(), Constants.ACTUALCALLOUTFLAG, eventPostSchedules.getName(), eventPostSchedules.getActCallIn(), eventPostSchedules.getActCallOut(), eventPostSchedules.getActCallOut()));


        agencyWorker = new TextField(eventPostSchedules.getAgencyWorker(), null, 5, TextArea.ANY);

        position.setUIID("workersList");
        name.setUIID("workersList");
        callInOutLabel.setUIID("workersList");
        actualCallIn.setUIID("workersListEditable");
        actualCallOut.setUIID("workersListEditable");
        agencyWorker.setUIID("workersListEditable");

        workerBreak.setUIID("workersList");

        if (Display.getInstance().isPortrait()) {
            postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(16, 8), position);
            postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(15, 8), name);
            postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(24, 8), callInOutLabel);
            postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(13, 8), actualCallIn);
            postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(13, 8), actualCallOut);
            postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(13, 8), agencyWorker);
            if (workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks() != null && !"".equals(workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks()) && "1".equals(workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks()))
                postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(6, 8), workerBreak);
        } else {
            postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(13, 10), position);
            postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(18, 10), name);
            postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(20, 10), callInOutLabel);
            postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(13, 10), actualCallIn);
            postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(13, 10), actualCallOut);
            postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(16, 10), agencyWorker);
            if (workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks() != null && !"".equals(workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks()) && "1".equals(workerBreaksPreferences.getAllowbreaks()))
                postSchedulesListContainer.addComponent(getTableConstraint(7, 10), workerBreak);
        }
    }
    postScheduleTableContainer.add(postSchedulesListContainer);
    return postScheduleTableContainer;
}

}
}
public TableLayout.Constraint getTableConstraint(int widthPercent, int heightPercent) {
    TableLayout.Constraint tableConstraint = new TableLayout.Constraint();
    tableConstraint.setWidthPercentage(widthPercent);
    tableConstraint.setHeightPercentage(heightPercent);
    return tableConstraint;
}
}
```

[image: this is in 1920x1200 resolution]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use flow layout for large dynamic data. You border layout with center constraint or absolute center.

Flow layout is overly simplistic and shouldn't be used for complex structures since Codename One doesn't reflow. There is a big discussion of that in the developer guide.